# On the off-chance

Tags: word-usage

when using 'on the off-chance', is that thing unlikely to happen always something we hope to happen, or could it also be something negative that we fear could happen?

For example, I can say:

On the off-chance of you coming back already today, I cooked for two.

But could I also say:

On the off-chance of you losing your job, I've put some money aside.

Comment: It could be something negative however, the phrase is used for casual things .. more of a "either way is fine" sort of thing.  "I reserved seats for a movie in the off chance it rains and we can't have the picnic" would be find.  Also, in your first example "already" does not work.  "early" or "anyway" could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can something we hope does happen or we hope doesn't happen.

Both of your examples work well.